# Common stains for fungal microscopy

Tags: mycology, microscopy, staining

I recently got a light microscope to start exploring microscopic features of fungi (and to explore microscopy in general).

What are some of the most common and easily available stains used when preparing microscope slides for fungi? Which situations are they each best for?